# How can I increase the speed at which data is retrieved from Oracle's database using OCCI?

Tags: c++, occi

I have around 400,000 rows inside my database and my goal is to retrieve and write to file all those rows using OCCI in the while loop I have created. However this while loop is writing to file extremely slowly. Even when I remove the writing to file code it's still really slow.

The while loop writes about 2k rows to file per minute. 400,000 rows would take about 3 hours. Is there a way to speed this process up?

```
oracle::occi::Connection *conn = env->createConnection(userName, password, connectString);
oracle::occi::Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("some select statement");
oracle::occi::ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();

std::ofstream logFile("temp.txt", std::ios::app);

while ( rs->next( ) == oracle::occi::ResultSet ::Status::DATA_AVAILABLE ) 
{
 res = rs->getString( 1 );
 logFile << res << "\n";

}
```

Eventually my plan is to add the rows to a struct or a class since I'll have more than one column.

Comment: Is the database optimised for the query you are running ?  Check this by submitting the select statement to database query plan analyser tool.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but a cursory Google suggests that each call to next() might require communicating with the database to get a record.  Have you tried using setDataBuffer to create a larger buffer and then calling next with a larger number of rows (say, 1000 at a time) and seeing if that improves performance?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I have not tried that, that might be exactly what I am looking for! Theoretically I could just call a buffer that contains 400k rows then but I'll see how efficient that will be once I try 1000 rows first. Thanks!